# Select and display latest column of the table with its corresponding row in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table as shown below

[image]

I want to display this table such that it shows only single ResourceStatus which is latest one as shown below

[image]

This is dummy data. I have multiple records which has NULL as a ResourceStatus for many employees.

I have tried to do so but it shows only NULL in my result table.

Comment: Do you have any timestamps in your table so you know which one is most recent?

Comment: Unless you have a date-time column in there somewhere which is set to the date-time that the row was added (a "CreatedOn" or "DateAdded" column), there's no way to deterministically know which was the 'latest'.  If you have such a row, then it's pretty straight-forward.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to make something like this work.

Using CTE, we add a serial number for each employee record. `Chetan KS` has only 1 record, so his record will have only 1 serial number. `Amita Rawal` has 3 records, so she will get serial 1, 2 and 3.

Then we extract the highest serial number for each employee (e.g. Sr #1 for Chetan and Sr #3 for Amita). This information is compared with the previous set of information to extract all the remaining fields.

```
-- add serial number to each employee record
with serial as (
  select *,
    row_number() over(partition by employeecode order by employeecode) as sr
  from test
),
-- get highest serial number for each employee
highest_serial as (
  select employeecode, max(sr) as maxsr
  from serial
  group by employeecode
)
-- extract the record with highest serial number
select a.*
from serial a
inner join highest_serial b
  on a.employeecode = b.employeecode
  and a.sr = b.maxsr
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5e7e9/8

You **should/will have to** modify this query to your use-case.